# Why does ε-differential privacy protect the subset of 1/ε edges in terms of graphs?

Tags: data-privacy, differential-privacy

In the book [The Algorithmic Foundations of Differential Privacy](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Eaaroth/Papers/privacybook.pdf) by Cynthia Dwork, Aaron Roth on page 24, databases that take the form of graphs are discussed.

> We could on the other hand consider differential privacy at a level
> of granularity corresponding to edges, and ask our algorithms to be
> insensitive only to the addition or removal of single, or small numbers
> of, edges from the graph. This is of course a weaker guarantee, but
> might still be sufficient for some purposes. Informally speaking, if we
> promise **$\epsilon$-differential privacy** at the level of a single edge, then no data
> analyst should be able to conclude anything about the existence of any
> subset of **$1/\epsilon$** edges in the graph. In some circumstances, large groups
> of social contacts might not be considered sensitive information: for
> example, an individual might not feel the need to hide the fact that
> the majority of his contacts are with individuals in his city or workplace,
> because where he lives and where he works are public information. On
> the other hand, there might be a small number of social contacts whose
> existence is highly sensitive (for example a prospective new employer,
> or an intimate friend). In this case, edge privacy should be sufficient
> to protect sensitive information, while still allowing a fuller analysis of
> the data than vertex privacy. Edge privacy will protect such an individual’s sensitive information provided that he has fewer than **$1/\epsilon$** such
> friends.

How do they derive the number $\large\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ in this discussion? Does the amount of $\epsilon$ still stand for privacy loss? Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a reference to group privacy. See Theorem 2.2 in the Dwork-Roth book.

If you have $(\varepsilon,0)$-differential privacy for changing 1 edge, then you have $(1,0)$-differential privacy for changing $1/\varepsilon$ edges.